# XCode not autogenerating Obj. C code from .h to .m source file

Tags: xcode

I'm following Nick Kuh's book on how to make iPhone Apps. I'm a beginner. I'm on Chapter 4. I'm stuck at the point where I clicked and dragged from the view to view controller. The program isn't autogenerating in the .m source file (for example: not coming up in .m source file as @sythesize dealerCard1, and so on). I'm I supposed to write these in or should it automatically do it for me? Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hello yes you should have to write these for the most part. I am assuming you were using the UI looking thing when you dragged the view to the controller? Anyways In the .h file you will probably need something equivalent to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myDraggedView;
```

and then in the .m file you will probably need

```
@sythesize myDraggedView
```

Then you will need to connect that property to the view you dragged onto the controller. But you should google how to do that as there are better tutorials then what I can write right now. But you should look for hookup events with objects in interface builder. Anyways good luck!

Comment: If this is helpful please mark it up or as the solution. Also if you have more question just comment and I will add them to the solution.

Comment: This is very wrong. 1. You shouldn't `retain` `IBOutlet` properties. They should be `weak`. 2. Xcode doesn't need `@synthesize` directives anymore. 3. If you were to write your own `@synthesize` directive for some reason you should use `@synthesize myDraggedView = _myDraggedView`.

Comment: You must be new to iPhone or something. he did not specify at all what version he was using and this used to be true in the olden days haha.

Comment: If he's just starting out, why would he be using an old version of Xcode? If you were really trying to be version-agnostic you would have also included an ivar in the interface bound to the `@synthesize`.

Comment: I am just starting out (have zero knowledge of  Xcode, trying to teach myself). I hold have stating that. I am 100% new to this. I am reading Nick Kuh'd Iphone Development App book and am stuck on chapter 4 (building a blackjack game). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Xcode isn't generating `@synthesize` because it isn't needed anymore. The compiler knows how to generate @synthesize at compile-time for you.

Your code will build and run fine -- with or without the @synthesize in place.